# How to use Ng-Bootstrap Nav with Child components as tabs?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the **[Nav](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview)** Component from [Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/) which is used like this (from the official examples):

```html
// Working Official Example:
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-tabs">

  <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
    <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <p>Content for One</p>
    </ng-template>
  </li>

  <li [ngbNavItem]="2">
    <a ngbNavLink>Two</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <p>Content for Two</p>
    </ng-template>
  </li>

  // etc...
</ul>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="mt-2"></div>
```

But having large amounts of content in the same file makes it long and cluttered, so I want to put the Nav tabs inside a **child component**. I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```html
// What I want to achieve:
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-tabs">

  <tab-section-1></tab-section-1>

  <tab-section-2></tab-section-2>

  // etc...
</ul>

<div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav" class="mt-2"></div>
```

**Child component:**

```html
// tab-section-1
<li [ngbNavItem]="1">
  <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
  <ng-template ngbNavContent>
    <p>Content for One</p>
  </ng-template>
</li>
```

But it's not working :(

Changing between tabs work wonderfully and even the tab titles show up. But the tab *content* isn't rendered, most likely because it's `<ng-template>` and is rendered by ng-bootstrap in another div.

I've searched far and wide but found naught! Thanks ⭐

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different structure, but you can try to create components for the content inside `ng-template`. This way you wouldn't break the Nav functionality and still have your own components:

```
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" [(activeId)]="active" class="nav-tabs">

  <li [ngbNavItem]="1">
    <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <tab-section-1></tab-section-1>
    </ng-template>
  </li>

  <li [ngbNavItem]="2">
    <a ngbNavLink>Two</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <tab-section-2></tab-section-2>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd already thought of that, but I really want to include the _title_ of the section (`<a ngbNavLink>`) within the child component as well to keep all the child-related code within its own component. Any ideas for this? :)

Comment: I don't think there is a way to wrap the content of the `li` in a standalone component. The `Nav` has a specific structure, that require directives on the same level.

Comment: Ah, I see, so it's just "bad" design :( I resorted to your solution, with an added step of cumbersome inclusion of the title as well by having 2 templates in my component -- one for the showing of title, and the other for the content, so that I can use the same component with an attribute to toggle between title and content. It's ugly, but it works :) Thanks for replying!

Comment: I wouldn't call it bad design, it just seems that you will have to adapt your components according to the `Nav` structure.